# Is there a way to execute a text string as a command?

Tags: netlogo

In NetLogo is there a way to treat a text string as a command and execute it?

In the simplest case - is there way to simply generate a text string like "forward " concatenated with a number I don't know till runtime, so i end up with a text variable equal to "forward 8", say,  and then execute that command?

My immediate need is probably what LOGO did,  namely, have the user click buttons to move a turtle around with the pen down to draw some shape, say a square,   saving those commands as they are written to an output window,  saving the full text of the output window to some named text like "draw-square",  and then have the user able to type "draw-square" in the command center and have the turtle execute those steps and draw a new square.

I could work around this I suppose by exporting the output to a myfile.nls text file,  then restarting NetLogo to bring in the new command file using the __includes [ "myfile.nls"] step , but I'd rather not ask them to do that if I can avoid it and in any case that wouldn't work over the web.

Comment: `run` and `runresult` both work on strings:  https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jasper answered the question in the comment above -- "run" and "runresult" do what I wanted.